# Mostrar query sql del Facade DB::select

Tags: mysql, laravel, select

Quisiera saber si existe una forma de ver el sql resultante del método estático select del Facade DB de Laravel .
Con el fin de saber cómo está haciendo el binding en la condición del where.
Por ejemplo:
`$result=DB::select("select name from users where type=?",[1]);`
No sé si el sql resultante es `select name from users where type=1` o si es `select name from users where type='1'`. Y eso impacta en el tiempo en que tarda en obtener el resultado.

Comment: La salida será como pongas el parámetro, si con comillas, con comillas, si sin comillas, sin comillas. De todos modos, deberías pasar el dato según el tipo. Si es numérico sin comillas, de lo contrario con comillas. Aunque por lo general el SGBD fuerza una conversión, pero si le evitamos ese trabajo adicional, mejor. De todos modos, ¿hay algo que justifique este uso, cuando puedes hacerlo de este modo: `DB::table('users')->select('name')->where('type','=',1)`?

Comment: Si [revisas la documentación](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queries#select-statements) verás que en varias partes pone: *The example above will produce the following SQL:*  y te muestra la instrucción que producirá.

Comment: Tienes toda la razón, amigo.
Para ser sincero no tengo ninguna justificación; recién comienzo y `select` me parecía el método adecuado. Indagaré un poca más la documentación para encontrar las diferencias y los casos en donde es mejor usar una sobre la otra.
Mil gracias por tus comentarios :).

Answer (score 0):

Puede hacer algo como esto :

```
$builder = DB::query(); 
//Añades filtros y cosas a tu query...
//..
//..
$addSlashes = str_replace('?', "'?'", $builder->toSql());
//Visualizas la query en SQL
vsprintf(str_replace('?', '%s', $addSlashes), $builder->getBindings());
```